# Value in the last row of the uitableview changing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, uilabel

I am having an UITableView where i have labels in each row with a float value. and the last the label in the last row should display the total Amount.

its showing the total amount fine but if the tableView is scrolled offscreen and returned the amount is getting increased.

```
 if(tableView == self.allTab)
{
if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        self.firstLabel.text = @"Category";
        self.firstLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.secondLabel.text = @"Date";
        self.secondLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.thirdLabel.text = @"Amount";
        self.thirdLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }  

else if(indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        NSManagedObject *records = nil;
        records = [self.listOfExpenses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.firstLabel.text = [records valueForKey:@"category"];
        NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[records valueForKey:@"date"]];
        NSString *dateWithInitialFormat = dateString;
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
        NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateWithInitialFormat];
        [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
        NSString *dateWithNewFormat = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
        self.secondLabel.text = dateWithNewFormat;
        NSString *amountString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[records valueForKey:@"amount"]];
        self.thirdLabel.text = amountString;
        totalAmount = totalAmount + [amountString doubleValue];
    }

else if(indexPath.section == 2)
{
        self.firstLabel.text = @"Total";
        self.firstLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.thirdLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",totalAmount];
        self.thirdLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.thirdLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
}
}
```

Comment: make `totalAmount = 0;` before updating the value.

Comment: I think totalamount is added to the previous totalamount value when you are scrolling the tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not calculate total inside cellForRowAtIndexPath because when it scrolls it again calculate the total so calculate total in some other method as follows:

```
-(float)calculateTotal
{
    totalAmount = 0;
   for(int i =0;i<[self.listOfExpenses length];i++)
   {
      NSManagedObject *records = nil;
        records = [self.listOfExpenses objectAtIndex:i];
      NSString *amountString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[records valueForKey:@"amount"]];
      totalAmount = totalAmount + [amountString doubleValue];
   }

 return totalAmount;
}
```

and assign it as follows:

```
 self.thirdLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[self calculateTotal]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Where have you declared totalAmount? Have you made it an instance variable? That is why it is retaining its value. Instead, you should declare totalAmount locally and initialize it to zero.

Something like:

```
else if(indexPath.section == 1)
{
    double totalAmount = 0.0;
    //.... Your code... And then Calculate totalAmount.
}
```

I think it shall work this way.